# Children's book where forest animals help a baby deer find his medal

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a young children's book from the 1970s I won in a reading competition at Nursery, so for ages 3-4 years old. The little fawn loses his medal from around his neck and feels very sad. All the forest animals start to help him look for it and finally find it for him in a bush, if I remember correctly.